# How to trigger listener after 1 particular bean initialized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, listener

Does anybody know if it is possible to create Spring Boot listener that would be called once only 1 particular bean has been initialized?

I only know how to create listener that is triggered once all beans have been initialized:

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void myListener(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {...}
```

But that listener will be triggered for every single bean in the app instead of 1 particular bean I am looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how this could be done.

First make your bean publish an event when it's initialized by implementing `InitializingBean` or having a `@PostConstruct` method:

```java
public class SomeBeanInitializedEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    ...
    public SomeBeanInitializedEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeBean implements InitializingBean {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new SomeBeanInitializedEvent(this));
    }
}
```

Or as a `@Bean` method use the standard `ApplicationEventPublisher` available in the context:

```java
@Bean 
public SomeBean someBean(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
    SomeBean someBean = ...
    publisher.publishEvent(new SomeBeanInitializedEvent(someBean));
    return someBean;
}
```

Then create an event listener for your event:

```java
private class SomeBeanInitializedEventApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<SomeBeanInitializedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SomeBeanInitializedEvent event) {
        log.info("Got SomeBeanInitializedEvent: {}", event);
    }
}
```

Then register this application event listener via `spring.factories` or the setter method on `SpringApplication`/`SpringApplicationBuilder`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SomeApplication.class)
                .listeners(new SomeBeanInitializedEventApplicationListener())
                .run(args);
    }
...
```

You cannot use an `@EventListener` annotated method in this case because it'll be registered as a listener too late, after an event from your bean has already been fired.

Comment: What if my Bean is not at class level but at method level? Let's say I have '@Configuration' class and need to wait until Bean at method level is initialized.

Comment: Updated for the `@Bean` method case

Comment: Will using DependsOn on the listener not work with the EventListener?